# INDEX MATCH obtaining values for duplicate names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one example table with the following data in `Sheet1`  with the following random data

```
------A ----------------- B ----------------------C ------------------------D  
1 --First--------------Last-----------------Start Date--------------End Date  
2 --John--------------Smith--------------08/08/2014------------01/01/2015  
3---John--------------Smith--------------08/11/2014------------17/11/2014  
4---John--------------Smith--------------06/06/2014------------23/12/2014  
5---Abel--------------Jones--------------14/05/2014------------29/04/2015  
6---Abel--------------Jones--------------04/07/2014------------26/04/2015
```

Then I have another table in `Sheet2`

```
------A ----------------- B ----------------------C ------------------------D  
    1 --First--------------Last-----------------Start Date--------------End Date  
    2 --John--------------Smith---------------------------------------------------  
    3---John--------------Smith---------------------------------------------------  
    4---John--------------Smith---------------------------------------------------  
    5---Abel--------------Jones---------------------------------------------------  
    6---Abel--------------Jones---------------------------------------------------
```

I am using `INDEX MATCH` to transfer the data between the two sheets.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,
MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet1!$A:$A=$A3)*(Sheet1!$B:$B=$B3),0),0))
```

To populate `column C` with the start dates from `Sheet1`.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,
    MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet1!$A:$A=$A3)*(Sheet1!$B:$B=$B3),0),0))
```

and this to populate `column D` with the end dates.

The problem is, when I perform this `INDEX MATCH` function, for a duplicate name, it will only copy over the first value. So this formula will paste `08/08/2014` into all 'John Smith' Start dates in `column C` of `Sheet2`.

How do I obtain all values so that `C2` should be `08/08/2014`, `C3` should be `08/11/2014`, `C4` should be `06/06/2014` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to insert a column in both sheets with a "running count" of instances of the same name. For example, insert `col C` and in `C2` enter `=IF(A2&B2 = A1&B1, C1+1, 1)`. This starts the count at 1 if the concatenated first and last name is new, and increases the previous count by 1 if not. So you would have

```
First     Last         Count by Person
John      Smith        1
John      Smith        2
John      Smith        3
Abel      Jones        1
Abel      Jones        2
George    Washington   1
Thomas    Jefferson    1
Thomas    Jefferson    2
```

You can then add this column to your `MATCH()` function (and change the lookup column as necessary).

Edit: It is worth noting that this requires your raw data is sorted by name.

Comment: Ah ok, so you are proposing an extension of the Match -- =INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,
MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet1!$A:$A=$A2)*(Sheet1!$B:$B=$B2) * (Sheet1!$C:$C=$C2),0),0))               -- This works. I am however hoping that there is a way to incorporate this into an array formula without having to introduce two new columns. The layout of my larger more complex spreadsheet is quite strict in its layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow the $A:$A refferances to something like $Ax+1:$Ay where y = last row of your excel sheet and x is position of previous occurance of this name/surname (you could store this in some dummy column).